# InDesign, XML, and Anchored Elements

Tags: adobe-indesign, xml

Is there a method in InDesign to anchor dynamic elements without XML becoming nested?

I have an XML imported that is a long list of field entries, each relating to text items on multiple pages of an Indesign file. When I make test frames dynamic and anchor them together the XML structure is affected, so when I import a different language variant XML the structure is no longer recognised and fields are not update and/or removed altogether

Comment: That's because XML within Indesign is only about text. So when you anchor some textframe within a story, you actually move text contents and applied tags. Eventually the structure is all messy. I know it s…